# Cakephp: cannot login if using a theme

Tags: cakephp

I am not a newbie cakephp developer however I won't call myself as an intermediate level cakephp programmer.

I came across a strange behavor what I could not handle.

I've build up an app with default views. First customer needs themeing so I decided to use the cakephp theme feature and started to make a theme with views, layouts etc.

I am using cakephp 1.3.8.

Everything works fine except I can't log in. Cakephp redirects me to an impossible place, the search controller with search results. It simply could not happen.
With the default views everything works fine.

What could be the reason? Could it be a bug in Auth component? Where should I start to debug this and how?

Thanks.

**edit:**

I made a copy of my default views into a new theme, and changed the $theme variable to this new theme. Everything works, so Auth and Theme facilities are fine, the reason should be my first theme. How a theme, or view file affects on login processing and/or Auth redirections? I still do not know how to find the bug in my views :(. I've set debug to 2, also checked the logs in tmp/logs but there ares now infos. Any idea?

Comment: by theming, you mean you have a different layout, correct? Where do you set the layout? I'd say post the code where you set up Auth and in routes file here.

Comment: no, I use different layouts within a theme (admin.ctp and default.ctp). By theming I mean using cakephp's theme facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I found the problem, a $this->Form->end() was missing from the searchbox element so the login data was submitted to the products controller search method, therefore the login wasn't processed.

Was my fault.

Comment: Mark your solution as the answer so that the question won't show in the unanswered questions list.

Comment: Yes thanks for warning, but I am allowed to do it after 2 days ;)